# Does a water softener only need to be plugged in to recharge?

Tags: water-softener

I gutted my house and have yet to get an outlet wired in by my water softener.  I still use hot water on occasion while I'm at the house so I want to make sure the water is still softened to avoid deposits in my water heater, pipes, and faucets.  Based on my understanding of how water softeners work, I should be able to run an extension cord to it once a week or so to recharge it, and then can leave it unplugged otherwise, correct?  There is no other reason it would need to be plugged in when it's not recharging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, no "real" problem at all. But, of course, a timer activated recharge won't work, you'll have to start the recharge manually by advancing the timer.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I can recharge my water softener on demand which makes it pretty trivial.